# how do i change the default behavior of session storing in the database

Tags: codeigniter

I enabled to store session data in the database and on every page refresh a new record gets inserted and ends up filling the session table with many rows. How can i just set it to insert a record only if no entry exists for its ip and update an existing ip?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions have a timeout which you can set in the config.php file (i.e `$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200` ). Once that time has reached, they expire and are deleted (through the session garbage collection mechanism).

> . How can i just set it to insert a record only if no entry exists for its ip

It dosent create a new session record for each update, it simply adds/remove data from the existing session record for the given IP and user agent if the option is selected (unless the session has expired in which case it creates a new record). Codeigniter has a builtin garbage collection mechanism which will eventually (if not instantly) delete the expired session.

> and update an existing ip?

Why would it update an existing ip and override its session data? that makes no sense. You could end up overwriting session data of a user who is currently using the session. If a user has stopped using the system, the session will evnetually expire and be deleted.

According to codeigniter [session class page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html):

> When a page is loaded, the session class will check to see if valid
>   session data exists in the user's session cookie. If sessions data
>   does not exist (or if it has expired) a new session will be created
>   and saved in the cookie. If a session does exist, its information will
>   be updated and the cookie will be updated. With each update, the
>   session_id will be regenerated.